# Why do my sliced letters look bad?

Tags: critique, optical-illusion

I’m working on a small project for a friend. I’m slicing letters but when I separate them I notice they look unaligned. Is it the font I’m using (I’ve already tried different fonts) or am I doing something wrong? Is it an optical illusion?

[image: sample]

Comment: You need to compensate for the gap so the viewer's eye continues along the original path.

Comment: ^ Yes. By cutting the letters and moving the the parts away from each other, you are distorting the patterns people's eyes are used to reading (that's all letters are, after all. Patterns). Instead of cutting + separating, try just covering/removing the center chunks of the letters, and see how that looks. The human eye is VERY good at filling in missing pieces (try googling "Gestalt Principles Closure" to learn a little more about that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are unaligned because that's what you are literally doing...you are cutting letters in half and then misaligning them by spreading the parts apart.

Normally, when this 'overlaid banner' technique is uses it's truly an overlay. You're not cutting any letters, but just overlaying on top of whole letters.

What would help in your example is to use a base font that condensed (ie, taller than they are wide). That way you can overlay your banner without having to manipulate the original type much. Something like this as a suggestion:

[image]

Comment: ahhh ok i get it so basically leaving the last name alone instead of slicing it and putting the rest on top..... let me give it a try

Comment: YAAAAAY it worked!! and to think i was up till 3 am last night trying to figure out how to slice a letter..... THANKS for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!